# interrupt coded by assembly and main coded by c++ isn't combined - (AVR programming)

Tags: assembly, interrupt, atmelstudio

I'm making pwm motor driver. And I have written interrupt routine using assembler for speed. honestly, I have revised lss file produced by atmel studio. and I have written main source using atmel studio 7. But there is no function combine C++ and assembler in atmel studio. And It does not have function inserting object file in toolchain option. So I compile and link in prompt(Windows 10). But I cannot get a result that I want.

1. interrupt source

```
#include <avr/io.h>

.global __vector_13

.extern INDEX_carrier_nth_section
.extern Mf
.extern TOP
.extern Io
.extern tick_rr
.extern Clock_Per_quarter_Cycle_of_Carrier
.extern PWM_duty_clocks

__vector_13:
    push    r0  
    in  r0, 0x3f    ; 63
    push    r1  
    eor r1, r1  
    ......
    ......
```

2. C++ source

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define F_CPU       16000000UL
#define NEWTON_ITER 3
#define U_LIMIT_Mf  601
#define Irm         3.0       // A
#define Vs          310.0     // V
#define Lr          20e-6     // H
#define Cr          1e-9      // F
....
....
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)  //for debug
{
    ;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Replace with your application code */

    full_length_of_power_clock = static_cast<long>(Mf)*Clock_Per_1_Cycle_of_Carrier;
    half_length_of_power_clock = full_length_of_power_clock>>1;
    quarter_length_of_power_clock = half_length_of_power_clock>>1;

    TOP = Clock_Per_1_Cycle_of_Carrier/4;

    get_pwm_dutys();
    start_PWM();
        ......
        ......
```

and I run gcc

```
avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p -o main.o main.cpp
```

and I run assembler

```
avr-as -mmcu=atmega328p -o interrupt.o interrupt.asm
```

and then

```
avr-gcc -o pwm.elf main.o interrupt.o
```

There was no error message.

and I saw output file by

```
avr-objdump -d pwm.elf
```

It said

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <__ctors_end>:
       0:       0c 94 44 00     jmp     0x88    ; 0x88 <__init>
       4:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
       8:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
       c:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      10:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      14:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      18:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      1c:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      20:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      24:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      28:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      2c:       0c 94 6e 00     jmp     0xdc    ; 0xdc <__vector_11>
      30:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      34:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      38:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      3c:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      40:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      44:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      48:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      4c:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      50:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      54:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      58:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      5c:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      60:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      64:       0c 94 6c 00     jmp     0xd8    ; 0xd8 <__bad_interrupt>
      68:       05 a8           ldd     r0, Z+53        ; 0x35
      6a:       4c cd           rjmp    .-1384          ; 0xfffffb04 <_ZL8tick_rcb+0xfefff984>
      6c:       b2 d4           rcall   .+2404          ; 0x9d2 <__addsf3x+0x82>
      6e:       4e b9           out     0x0e, r20       ; 14
      70:       38 36           cpi     r19, 0x68       ; 104
```

only TIMER1_COMPA_vect(__vector_11) exist. There isn't __vector_13.

In order to refer to atmel studio's output, I add --save-temps option in atmel studio. And main.s by atmel is like this.

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
__SP_H__ = 0x3e
__SP_L__ = 0x3d
__SREG__ = 0x3f
__tmp_reg__ = 0
__zero_reg__ = 1
    .text
.Ltext0:
    .cfi_sections   .debug_frame
    .section    .text.__vector_11,"ax",@progbits
.global __vector_11
    .type   __vector_11, @function
__vector_11:
.LFB6:
    .file 1 ".././main.cpp"
    .loc 1 67 0
    .cfi_startproc
    push r1
```

I change the code regarding __vector_13.

```
.text
    .section    .text.__vector_13,"ax",@progbits
.global __vector_13
__vector_13:
```

But It doesn't give what I want.
Somebody help me.

Comment: You need to specify `-mmcu=atmega328p` when linking too. Also, your compilation step should use `-c`.

Comment: thanks. it works!! BTW why does not it show error?